# Canvas disappears when animating "source-in" globalCompositeOperation mask

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I'm using "source-in" compositing gradient mask on a canvas and I want to animate the stretching of the mask shape & gradient. Here's the compositing code, a function called `drawList`:

```
var r = ctx.createLinearGradient(1100, 0, 1200 + stretch,0);
r.addColorStop(0,"rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0");
r.addColorStop(0.8,"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0");
ctx.fillStyle = r;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.fillRect(300, 0, 1200 + stretch, 1000);
```

`stretch` starts at 0 and increases in an animating function using `requestAnimationFrame`, which I have verified works when animating a simple rectangle or even `ctx.clearRect(300, 0, 1200 + stretch, 1000)`. The animation function calls `drawList` on each iteration and the `drawList`.

Upon loading the list text from `drawList` fades according to the gradient fill of the rectangle above. The problem I'm running into is that as soon as the animation function is called, the canvas is erased and doesn't redraw the list. I would use ctx.clip(), but I really need the gradient fill to create the fade effect.

Any ideas? Is this a limitation of canvas?

Comment: Sounds about what you would expect. Everything drawn before the rect will disappear, But you should see the gradient rect. Dont forget to set the comp back to source-over after the rect. or use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` to reset GPU states.

Comment: @Blindman67 save() & restore() were just the ticket. Thanks, man. Can you submit an answer so I can mark it as the solution and you can get the rep pts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting canvas context states such as `globalAlpha`, `globalCompositeOperation`, `clip`, etc... these states remain active and can affect the rest of your rendering. One way to solve this is to set all the states again after you have used them. This can end up in a lot of extra code so the 2Dcontext API provides two handy functions to control the state. `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`

`ctx.save()` pushes the current state to a stack. `ctx.restore()` pops the last saved state and sets the canvas context to that state. You can nest saves, but remember to match each save with a restore.

For more info see [ctx.save() at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save#Drawing_state)

A word of warning. Saving and restoring states should be avoided if you are after high performance rendering for realtime games and interfaces. State changes can be a stall point when rendering, or just replicate unneeded state changes. Restoring a state may force the GPU to reload from CPU memory a bitmap used by `ctx.createPattern()` in a previously saved state, even if you are not intending to use it. This can be very slow and have a major performance hit on your frame rate, especially if you keep restoring to that unused pattern.